# Installation of NodeJS in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, cordova, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed node.js and the version is 0.6.12 . I am trying to update it but the efforts are invain.Even though i have installed the latest version the Terminal still shows the version as 0.6.12 which means that the installation is not successfull.
Please help . The screen shot is http://tinypic.com/r/nx3wo6/8

Comment: You should ask this question in http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Also try to invoke nodejs -v

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing software on Ubuntu. This belongs to askubuntu.com

Comment: let me google it for you ... [https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `chris-lea/node.js` ppa, so:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Also if you want to learn more [here is](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) a pretty decent reference.